# Tratamiento y Manipulacion de Arreglo PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo la siguiente consulta mysql:

```
    $conexion->query("SET @index:=0");
    
    $consulta = "SELECT

    @index:=@index+1 AS 'index',
    tr.nombre AS trabajador,
    tr.rut,
    GROUP_CONCAT(mes.id ORDER BY mes.id) as id_mes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(mes.nombre_mes ORDER BY mes.id) as mes,
    ROUND(SUM(lq.total_haberes_imp - lq.total_desc_legales)) AS renta_total,
    ROUND(SUM(lq.iut)) AS iut,
    ROUND(SUM(lq.total_hab_noimponibles)) AS no_gravada

    FROM mes mes

    LEFT JOIN apertura_sueldos am ON am.mes = mes.id AND am.ano = 2022
    LEFT JOIN liquidaciones lq ON lq.apertura_sueldos = am.id AND lq.id_tr IN($trs) AND lq.empresa = 2
    LEFT JOIN trabajadores tr ON tr.id = lq.id_tr

    GROUP BY tr.id ORDER BY tr.rut ASC";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {

            $ci = $row['rut'];
            $dig = substr($ci,strlen($ci)-1,1);
            $dig = strtoupper($dig);
            $rut = number_format(substr($ci,0,strlen($ci)-1),0,".",".")."-".$dig;

            $content .= '

            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
                <tr>
                    <td width="25" align="center" style="font-size:8pt">'.$row['index'].'</td>
                    <td width="58" align="center" style="font-size:8pt">'.$rut.'</td>
                    <td width="48" align="right" style="font-size:8t">'.number_format($row['renta_total'], 0, ',', '.').'</td>
                    <td width="48" align="right" style="font-size:8pt; ">'.number_format($row['iut'], 0, ',', '.').'</td>
                    <td width="48" align="right" style="font-size:8pt; ">0</td>
                    <td width="48" align="right" style="font-size:8pt; ">'.number_format($row['no_gravada'], 0, ',', '.').'</td>
                    <td width="48" align="right" style="font-size:8pt; ">0</td>
                    <td width="48" align="right" style="font-size:8pt; ">0</td>

                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                    <td width="13" align="center" style="font-size: 8pt">SI/NO</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        ';

        }
    }
```

La variable $trs, que dentro del IN en JOIN de la consulta, contiene los id de todos los trabajadores que existen en el año 2022, que tiene esta estructura:

```
$trs = 106,9,35,21,4,20,8,211,123,245,19,124,32,91,18,271,276,140,268,7,267,37,239,3,11,270,283,278,131,43,281,2,25,282,24,179,222,217,226,230,216,242,233,204,1,26,219,266,174,236,84,145,141,95,172,41,218,274,177,279,17,220,47,14,261,36,13,167,277,273,138,42,205,272,176,234,235,39,46,206,31,27,170,5,228,207,244,190,229,12,221,133,248,44,238,280,215,243,209,224,232,262,223,208,119,237,275,45,29;
```

La consulta me devuelve estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la columna id_mes, los numeros que aparecen son los meses en los cuales el trabajador ha estado presente. Por ejemplo:

- para el caso 1, solo estuvo en Enero y para los otros meses, debería decir NO EXISTE.
- para el caso 2, estuvo todo el año (todos los meses del año).
- para la línea 8, comienza con 3 que seria marzo, entonces debería decir enero y febrero NO EXISTE, pero de ahí en adelante, debería decir SI EXISTE.

La idea de todo esto, es mostrar los meses en que estuvo presente con SI EXISTE y cuando no estuvo, mostrar NO EXISTE. Lo mas importante, es mantener la estructura de la tabla, ya que es un formato OBLIGATORIO y se debe mantener para el muestreo de datos.

Alguna idea para poder orientarme?
Gracias a todos.

Comment: pero tu problema es php o mysql?? en php se soluciona muy simplemente...

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder, el problema es php. Saludos

Comment: si el problema es php, donde esta tu codigo? porque pusiste mysql en la pregunta? y entonces, cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que tienes algo asi

```
$campoBaseDeDatos = [
    "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
    "1",
    "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"
];
```

Primero definimos un array con los meses

```
$arrayMeses=
[   
    1 => "Enero",
    2 => "Febrero",
    3 => "Marzo",
    4 => "Abril",
    5 => "Mayo",
    6 => "Junio",
    7 => "Julio",
    8 => "Agosto",
    9 => "Septiembre",
    10 => "Octubre",
    11 => "Noviembre",
    12 => "Diciembre"
];
```

Deberiamos recorrer cada Fila de la `basededatos` y cortar el `string` de los meses por el caracter `","`

```
#Pintamos el inicio de la Tabla
$html = "<table>";


#Recorremos la las filas de la base de datos
foreach($campoBaseDeDatos as $k => $meses){
    $html .= "<tr>";
    #Cortamos el string de los dias por el caracter ","
    $listaMesesTrabajados = explode(",",$meses);
    
    #Rellenamos los huecos antes del primer mes (Si es difererente a 1 )
    if($listaMesesTrabajados[0] != 1){
        for($i = 1; $i <= $listaMesesTrabajados[0];$i++){
            $html .= "<td>No Existe</td>";
        }
    }

    #pintamos el mes en su correspondiente hueco
    foreach($listaMesesTrabajados as $key => $mes){
        $html .= "<td>".$arrayMeses[$mes]."</td>";
    }


    #Rellenamos los huecos si el ultimo elemento del array no es 12
    if(end($listaMesesTrabajados) != 12){
        for($i = end($listaMesesTrabajados); $i <= 12;$i++){
            $html .= "<td>No Existe</td>";
        }
    }
    #fin de la fila
    $html .= "</tr>";
}


$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
```

Te dejo el codigo comentado paso a paso. Aunque Seguramente hay mejores formas de hacerlo.

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado, gracias por responder. Edite la pregunta para que se entienda mejor la problemática. Trate de implementar la solución que me diste, pero me entregaba 13 meses en vez de 12, es por ello que explique mejor el problema. Lo otro que hay que tener en cuenta, es la estructura de la tabla puesta en la pregunta, ya que es obligatoria. Saludos y gracias por tu ayuda.